# How to run Flask through wsgi?

Tags: apache, flask, wsgi

I am just trying to run a Hello World through a server and am getting wsgi errors.

My app is in /var/www/testapp
My file under this path is testapp.py
Code is ...

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
        return 'Hello, World'

if __name__ == "__main_":
    app.run()
```

Easy enough. It runs fine if I start it from the CLI ( 127.0.0.1:5000 )

Problem is when I try to run it through apache. I have a wsgi file in that same folder called testapp.wsgi

Code is here....

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/")
from testapp import app as application
```

The Apache conf file is this..

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName example.com
        WSGIDaemonProcess testapp
        WSGIScriptAlias /  /var/www/testapp/testapp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/testapp>
                WSGIProcessGroup testapp
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

The error I am getting is this in the apache log...

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 28774:tid 139666678216448] [remote xxxxxx:56870] mod_wsgi (pid=28774): Target WSGI script '/var/www/testapp/testapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Feb 15 19:53:01.769229 2019] 139666678216448] [remote xxxxxx:56870] mod_wsgi (pid=28774): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/testapp/testapp.wsgi'.
[Fri Feb 15 19:53:01.774590 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 28774:tid 139666678216448] [remote xxxxxx:56870] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Feb 15 19:53:01.774716 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 28774:tid 139666678216448] [remote xxxxxx:56870]   File "/var/www/testapp/testapp.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Feb 15 19:53:01.774785 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 28774:tid 139666678216448] [remote xxxxxx:56870]     from testapp import app as application
[Fri Feb 15 19:53:01.774875 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 28774:tid 139666678216448] [remote xxxxxx:56870] ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

I can't help but think it is something ridiculously simply. Can someone help point me in the right direction? JW

Comment: Missing ```__init__.py``` ?

Comment: This is my first time attempting to run a Flask app through Apache and I can certainly try that. Upvoted.